# How do you match an element in the entire dataframe and return the entire row or index of that particular matched element?

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

Each row in this dataframe represents an order and executionStatus.x has some info about the order status.

Those executionStatus.x columns are automatically created by flatten_json by 
amirziai, depending on how many arguments there are. So if there are 3 statuses for one order like in row 0, there will be up to executionStatus.2. Since row 1 and 2 only have one status, it only has values in executionStatus.0.

My problem is I cannot match "ORDER_FULFILLED" because I don't know how many executionStatuses there will be and I would need to write the exact column name like so df[df['executionStatus.0'].str.match('ORDER_FULFILLED')].

```
         executionStatus.0 executionStatus.1 executionStatus.2  \
0  REQUESTED_AMOUNT_ROUNDED              MEOW   ORDER_FULFILLED   
1           ORDER_FULFILLED               NaN               NaN   
2     NOT_AN_INFUNDING_LOAN               NaN               NaN   

   investedAmount  loanId  requestedAmount  OrderInstructId  
0            50.0   22222             55.0            55555  
1            25.0   33333             25.0            55555  
2             0.0   44444             25.0            55555
```

Is there a way to get the entire row or index that matched with "ORDER_FULFILLED" element in the entire dataframe?

Ideally, the matched dataframe should look like this because row 0 and row 1 have ORDER_FULFILLED in the executionStatuses and row 3 does not so it should be excluded. Thanks!

```
investedAmount  loanId  requestedAmount  OrderInstructId  
0            50.0   22222             55.0            55555  
1            25.0   33333             25.0            55555
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`df.filter()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for getting the similar columns containing `executionStatus` with a boolean mask:

```
df[df.filter(like='executionStatus').eq('ORDER_FULFILLED').any(axis=1)]

          executionStatus.0 executionStatus.1 executionStatus.2  \
0  REQUESTED_AMOUNT_ROUNDED              MEOW   ORDER_FULFILLED   
1           ORDER_FULFILLED               NaN               NaN   

   investedAmount  loanId  requestedAmount  OrderInstructId  
0              50   22222               55            55555  
1              25   33333               25            55555
```

If you want to delete he `execution` columns from output, use:

```
df.loc[df.filter(like='executionStatus').eq('ORDER_FULFILLED').any(axis=1),\
           df.columns.difference(df.filter(like='executionStatus').columns)
```

Comment: So I am trying to do the opposite now by using ne instead of eq like so: df[df.filter(like='executionStatus').ne('ORDER_FULFILLED').any(axis=1)]. Is there a quick way to get the rows that arent showing "ORDER_FULFILLED"? Thanks.

Comment: Use an invert `df[~df.filter(like='executionStatus').eq('ORDER_FULFILLED').any(axis=1)]`